# Micronaut 2.0.0 - Unable to invoke one service from another on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, java-11, micronaut, docker-desktop, micronaut-client

I have a service called Identity from which I want to invoke another service called Notification. Both services are built with `Java 11`, `Micronaut 2.0.0` and are to be deployed on `kubernetes`.

The Notification service's kubernetes manifest look like this-

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: notification-service
  labels:
    app: notification-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: notification-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: notification-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: notification-service
          image: notification-service
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 3
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 3
            failureThreshold: 10
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: notification-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: notification-service
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
```

To invoke this service, I have added a declarative client in Identity service as follows-

```
@Client(id="notification-service")
public interface NotificationClient {

    @Get("/health")
    String checkHealth();
}
```

Whenever I invoke the `checkHealth()` method after injecting it in any service or controller, the request gets stuck.
The invocation works fine if I make the call from any service with Micronaut version 1.3.x.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: "Whenever I invoke the checkHealth() method after injecting it in any service or controller, the request gets stuck." - Does "stuck" mean that the call blocks and never returns?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, yes that's what's happening. On debugging, I can see that the service is getting resolved correctly but this seems like a problem with `http-client`.

Comment: I think the problem is that the controller is blocking the event loop.

Comment: @ÁlvaroSánchez-Mariscal- Woah! modifying the `NotificationClient` to return a `Single<String>` did the trick! Do you have any explanation or perhaps any documentation link explaining this behavior?

Comment: It's on the 2.0 upgrade notes in the documentation